# How can I get township and range edge labels in QGIS 3.4.13-Madeira

Tags: qgis, grids-graticules

I've created PLSS edge labels before with ESRI and older QGIS and don't remember this being all that hard, but for some reason I'm lost trying to get it done with the newer version.  The PLSS data is in the map as a layer and I'm using the atlas to create map pages.  How do I get the township and range to dynamically update the grid_x and grid_y label locations?